# Adding dimension in tableau line chart

Tags: charts, tableau-api, linechart, dimension

I am working on Tableau Line chart with dual axis.
However, I want to add dimension in those line chart and arrange by alphabet.
Please see the  [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UeRAwbGvNNErQlc1tXb1850Y9Dfk9G0V) here to download the packaged workbook.
What I wanted to do is as follow:

[image]

Can anyone advise me?
Thanks
Zep

Comment: can you downgrade the version to 10.3 and attach the workbook

Comment: Hi @Siva, Thanks for the prompt response. I have updated the link with Tableau V10.3. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way that I can think is to use the dashboard.

Created one more sheet with names in team and then added both sheets in dashboard, For color coding I would suggest you to define your own colors for all teams and add in both the sheets.

take file from this [link](https://ufile.io/2o1yq)

Comment: Dear Siva. Thanks for your help.If I want to sort the teams based on the rank of GW 1. How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: @Zephyr are you able to achieve the requriement?

Comment: @Zephyr can you post answer and then accept it, so that others can use. Also, its good practice to close the thread

Comment: Here is what I did to rank the team.
Create a calculated field (GW1Rank). The code is as follow:
If [GW]==1 then [Rank] else 0 End

Comment: @Zephyr if my answer helped you then only accept it, Else please post your response as another answer and then accept your own posted answer

Comment: I think I hv accepted it. Thanks Siva for your help